# How to align checkboxes horizontally next to each other and show form upon click?

Tags: javascript, html

i have been searching stackoverflow but, I am unable to find a solution pertaining to my problem.  What i want is when a  user clicks a checkbox, a form shows up.  I managed to get one checkbox and make the form show up, but having trouble putting checkboxes side by side next to each other.  So what i want is:

```
[] residential   [] commercial    [] industrial.
```

When a user clicks the above boxes, a form opens up on the same page.  My code:

edit: Thanks to @brk for the solution.  After copying the solution below, for some reason When i click on 'residential', i don't see anything popping up.  My code:

```
<script>
// Add event listener to each of the radio button
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="selectType"]').forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // get the data-type from this, this data-type will be used to
    // hide show relevant form
    let name = this.getAttribute('data-type');
    // hide previously displayed form
    if (document.querySelector('.formDisplay') !== null) {
      document.querySelector('.formDisplay').classList.remove('formDisplay');
    }
    // find the form whose name+_info is same as the name of the form 
    // & add a formDisplay to it
    document.querySelector('form[name="' + name + '_info"]').classList.add('formDisplay');

  })
})
</script>

<style>

form {
  display: none;
}

.formDisplay {
  display: block;
}

</style>

<html>

<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="checkboxR" data-type='res' name='selectType' type='radio'>
    <label for="checkboxR">Residential</label>
    <input id="checkboxC" data-type='com' name='selectType' type='radio'>
    <label for="checkboxC">Commercial</label>
    <input id="checkboxI" data-type='ind' name='selectType' type='radio'>
    <label for="checkboxI">Industrail</label>
  </div>

  <form name="res_info" action="/result/" method="get" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    Residential Form
  </form>
  <form name="com_info" action="/result/" method="get" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    Commercial Form
  </form>
  <form name="ind_info" action="/result/" method="get" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    Industrial Form
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

So, I see 3 radio buttons, but clicking on them doesn't open up anything.  Sorry im kinda new to html/css so this concept is new.

Comment: Er, why do you have `div`s and `input`s before the `body`?

Comment: This was just a continuation of a code i had written.  I didnt post the whole code.  Obviously its inside a block content.  The body part is the form i have.  form's name is cust_info.  It shows up after clicking the box.

Comment: So if user select multiple checkbox , multiple forms will be displayed?

Comment: no. im assuming he won't be smart enough to click on multiple checkboxes.  only one check box can be clicked at a time

Comment: Then you need radio button not checkbox

Comment: oh ok.  Can you post a solution then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make changes in your html and add another attribute `data-type` .This value will be used to display corresponding form.

Create tep css and initially hide all the forms. Add another class to display the form using `display:block`

Onclick of the radio button get the `data-type` find the forma whose name matches with this data-type and display that form

```js
// Add event listener to each of the radio button
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="selectType"]').forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // get the data-type from this, this data-type will be used to
    // hide show relevant form
    let name = this.getAttribute('data-type');
    // hide previously displayed form
    if (document.querySelector('.formDisplay') !== null) {
      document.querySelector('.formDisplay').classList.remove('formDisplay');
    }
    // find the form whose name+_info is same as the name of the form 
    // & add a formDisplay to it
    document.querySelector('form[name="' + name + '_info"]').classList.add('formDisplay');

  })
})
```

```css
form {
  display: none;
}

.formDisplay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="checkboxR" data-type='res' name='selectType' type='radio'>
    <label for="checkboxR">Residential</label>
    <input id="checkboxC" data-type='com' name='selectType' type='radio'>
    <label for="checkboxC">Commercial</label>
    <input id="checkboxI" data-type='ind' name='selectType' type='radio'>
    <label for="checkboxI">Industrail</label>
  </div>

  <form name="res_info" action="/result/" method="get" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    Residential Form
  </form>
  <form name="com_info" action="/result/" method="get" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    Commercial Form
  </form>
  <form name="ind_info" action="/result/" method="get" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    Industrial Form
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<body>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="horizontal">
            <input id="checkbox" type=checkbox> Residential</input>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal" id="delivery_div" style="display:none">
        <input  id="delivery" type=checkbox > etc </input>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
var delivery_div = document.getElementById('delivery_div');
checkbox.onclick = function() {
console.log(this);
if(this.checked) {
 delivery_div.style['display'] = 'block';
}  else {
 delivery_div.style['display'] = 'none';
  }
};

</script>
<style>
```

```html
<body>
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="horizontal">
      <input id="checkbox" type=checkbox> Residential</input>
 </div>
 <div class="horizontal" id="delivery_div" style="display:none">
      <input  id="delivery" type=checkbox > etc </input>
 </div>
</div>
<script>
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
var delivery_div = document.getElementById('delivery_div');
checkbox.onclick = function() {
console.log(this);
if(this.checked) {
 delivery_div.style['display'] = 'block';
}  else {
 delivery_div.style['display'] = 'none';
  }
};

</script>
<style>
.horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}
</style>
</body>
```

```
.horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}
</style>
</body>
```

Comment: wheres commercial?

Comment: You can replace input inside div with id="delivery_div" with 'commercial' and replace same code to display the form . just enter the form inside the div with id="delivery_div"